# How To Sum specific fields case when the record of this fields Common in ID?

Tags: linq, list

Well lets simplify my question i have `list of employee` this `list` contain this fields 
(`id`,`salary`,`name`) i will fill it for example

```
 1. (1,1000,Amgad)      
 2. (1,2000,Amgad)
 3. (2,100,Mohamed)
 4. (2,1000,Mohamed)
 5. (2,1500,Mohamed)
 6. (3,200,Mego)
 7. (3,200,Mego)
```

i want Linq Query that make the output As List That Contain

```
(1,3000,Amgad)
(2,2600,Mohamed)
(3,400,Mego)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
var tmp = list.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
              .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.ToList().OrderByDescending(o => o.Salary)).Select(s => s.Value.FirstOrDefault())
              .ToList()
              .Sum(s => s.Salary);
```

Comment: but i want `SUM`  this query don't sum ?!

Comment: Yes Thanks Man Worked Great :)